# Elasticsearch sorting with whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search index with name **clear** and type **positionTemplate**. It contains field called **title**. I had created this index/type using river jdbc plugin. I had changed mapping of title field using following api.

```
 PUT clear/positionTemplate/_mapping
{
    "mappings": {
        "positionTemplate": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

title filed contains following values :

*"Java Developer"*

*"C Developer"*

*"Ruby Developer"*

*"Java QA"*

*"Ruby QA"*

*"Java Dev"*

while running following query sorting is not proper.

```
{
  "sort" : [{
    "title" : {"order":"desc"}
  }], 
  "fields" : [ "title"]
}
```

output is :

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "Ruby Developer"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "ruby"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "Ruby QA"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "ruby"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "4",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "Java QA"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "qa"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "15",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "Java Dev"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "java"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "Java Developer"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "java"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "_index": "clear",
                "_score": null,
                "_type": "positionTemplate",
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "C Developer"
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    "developer"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "max_score": null,
        "total": 6
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 2
}
```

This is wrong. Can somebody guide me how to correct it ?

Comment: Are you sure your field is not analyzed? Because your result shows `"sort": ["ruby"]`, `"sort": ["java"]`, `"sort": ["developer"]` which is exactly the order it's supposed to be, but apparently title was analyzed.

Comment: I had changed mapping as mentioned. I have also similar doubt. How to verify not_analyzed is applied or not ?

Comment: You can retrieve the mapping from the server `http://localhost:9200/myIndex/myType/_mapping` (or more specifically just the [field mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html))

Comment: where you able to solve it? I'm currently facing the exact same issue. Sorting field is getting split by space although I have index: not_analyzed in the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

you need to re map the field.

Example:

```
{
  "<field name>": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then on sort propriety, you will need to specify the "keyword".

Example:

```
GET <index>/_search
{
  "sort": [
  {
    "<field name>.keyword": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```